# No open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

In section 11 of Munkres's *Analysis on Manfiolds*, question 2 asks you to prove that no open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but isn't the empty set open and of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: It's true for any other open set. Just put a cube inside it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a common "mistake" / "simplification" in mathematics to ignore obvious exceptions to statements, both in theorems and in exercises. At any rate, it says *"non-trivial open set"* in the paperback edition.